# The Most Complex Chinese Character

Tags: code-golf, graphical-output, kolmogorov-complexity

## Challenge

You must output the Chinese character for [biáng](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biangbiang_noodles). Your program must not access any external sources and must exactly reproduce [this SVG](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File%3ABi%C3%A1ng.svg) in every way. Note that the image below is just a gif version of the image.

The output should be an SVG file. Your program must be a program, therefore you cannot hardcode the SVG.

[image]

The shortest code wins.

---

Just in case Wikipedia goes down or changes the file, [here's](http://pastebin.com/UzeSqkJk) the SVG file you are required to output.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 15.0.2, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg version="1.1" id="svg2" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="500px" height="500px"
     viewBox="0 0 500 500" enable-background="new 0 0 500 500" xml:space="preserve">
<g>
    <path d="M408.997,122.382l3.629-2.032l-10.012-6.497l-10.009-6.497l-2.195,7.083c-2.958,9.552-8.487,20.773-14.003,28.416
        c-4.355,6.038-13.775,14.106-16.467,14.106c-1.68,0-1.755-0.338,1.861,8.345c1.729,4.151,3.555,8.729,4.06,10.174l0.918,2.628
        l3.079-2.823c1.695-1.553,2.253-3.035,8.304-4.512c6.57-2.126,17.534-4.232,19.088-3.667c0.664,0.242-2.23,5.356-6.649,11.744
        c-7.984,11.543-16.75,20.515-23.942,24.513l-4.021,2.23l2.822,5.478c1.553,3.012,3.536,6.505,4.409,7.765
        c1.581,2.29,1.583,2.29,5.064,0.121c4.438-2.765,10.479-4.206,26.281-6.271c6.966-0.912,14.321-1.902,16.349-2.202
        c3.173-0.472,3.769-0.204,4.293,1.928c0.602,3.25,0.421,6.658,1.686,9.72c1.433,2.916,2.298,2.712,6.408-1.512
        c6.831-7.014,5.967-13.847-3.337-26.405c-8.965-12.096-10.583-13.513-14.101-12.321l-2.938,0.995l4.938,9.333
        c2.719,5.134,4.939,9.727,4.939,10.207c-11.883,3.042-30.03,1.979-40.493-0.616c11.232-11.183,22.685-22.159,32.729-34.656
        c4.926-6.111,10.282-11.712,11.905-12.445c1.625-0.731,2.952-1.666,2.952-2.075c0-1.163-13.91-14.435-15.127-14.435
        c-0.598,0-1.084,0.441-1.084,0.98c0,0.54-1.685,5.007-3.74,9.931l-3.743,8.95h-15.509c-8.531,0-15.511-0.396-15.511-0.879
        C371.832,155.722,405.104,124.561,408.997,122.382z"/>
    <path d="M258.98,130.742c0.053,0.014,1.647-0.792,3.545-1.79c7.975-3.285-2.358-2.285,55.517-2.333l52.069-0.518l-10.669-10.107
        c-5.87-5.56-11.147-10.108-11.729-10.108s-5.587,2.333-11.124,5.184c-9.552,4.919-10.469,5.183-18.048,5.167l-7.983-0.018
        l3.958-2.316c2.174-1.272,4.808-3.489,5.847-4.924c5.623-7.761-5.982-19.346-28.117-28.067c-8.884-3.5-9.777-3.59-13.149-1.33
        l-2.516,1.685l8.925,8.95c4.908,4.921,10.896,11.744,13.305,15.16c2.41,3.415,5.583,7.258,7.053,8.539l2.671,2.327l-65.431,0.01
        L258.98,130.742z"/>
    <path d="M186.128,315.664c1.356-0.563,2.697-1.021,2.978-1.021c0.038,0.376,0.062,57.187,0.062,57.187l3.226,4.437l3.226,4.436
        l7.71-6.021c4.24-3.313,10.413-7.842,13.716-10.063c4.644-3.121,5.891-4.514,5.503-6.133c-0.314-1.307,1.66,0.127,5.251,3.818
        c3.164,3.254,8.144,7.801,11.064,10.108c5.021,3.969,5.406,4.092,7.052,2.301c2.273-2.476,7.671-4.899,10.908-4.899
        c1.841,0,2.566-0.59,2.566-2.082c0-1.574-2.016-2.967-8.248-5.701c-13.227-5.807-23.164-13.982-23.164-19.059
        c0-1.607,8.525-6.173,15.958-8.546c2.368-0.756,4.306-1.53,4.306-1.727s-2.229-4.16-4.956-8.813l-4.958-8.462l-4.235,7.304
        c-2.329,4.018-5.628,8.578-7.331,10.139c-3.63,3.326-3.103,3.846-9.879-9.668l-4.288-8.553h21.934
        c24.969,0,23.409,1.069,14.507-9.955l-4.778-5.918l-4.19,4.653l-4.189,4.654l-15.856-0.304l-15.855-0.305v-15.445l21.001-0.299
        l21.001-0.299l-4.147-7.426c-6.226-11.145-5.641-10.877-10.192-4.654l-4.025,5.506h-23.713l0.156-16.187
        c0,0,9.811-0.366,21.283-0.366h20.856l-2.92-4.137c-1.606-2.275-3.707-5.504-4.668-7.172c-0.961-1.67-2.208-3.035-2.771-3.035
        c-3.22,1.875-5.566,5.064-8.179,7.793l-23.601,0.083l-0.079-16.15l23.023-0.296l23.022-0.297l-5.762-8.254
        c-3.168-4.541-6.071-8.255-6.449-8.255s-2.347,2.371-4.377,5.271l-3.691,5.271l-27.793-0.132l-6.333-4.694l-6.333-4.694v78.42
        h-6.791h-6.792l3.884,4.332C183.125,316.086,184.001,316.543,186.128,315.664z M204.417,314.583c0,0,8.866,27.05,12.347,32.667
        c1.747,2.82,3.275,5.615,3.396,6.215c0.18,0.891-15.211,8.006-15.609,7.213C204.395,356.627,204.417,314.583,204.417,314.583z"/>
    <path d="M261.965,181.771c1.221,9.539,1.402,12.767,1.438,25.451c0.021,7.555,0.445,13.736,0.945,13.736l17.965-4.775l46.482-0.927
        l0.329,2.951c0.243,2.176,0.775,2.827,2.026,2.48c17.15-4.759,18.48-5.351,17.973-8.02c-0.273-1.428-0.788-4.786-1.147-7.462
        l-0.65-4.867l5.256-3.307c4.265-2.687,4.999-3.544,3.904-4.574c-5.08-4.773-18.053-15.041-19.002-15.041
        c-0.636,0-3.405,1.167-6.154,2.591c-4.897,2.54-5.468,2.592-28.083,2.591c-21.454,0-30.73-0.863-40.001-3.72
        C261.818,178.44,261.602,178.93,261.965,181.771z M282.587,194.416l46.771-0.173l-0.059,10.129h-46.714L282.587,194.416
        L282.587,194.416z"/>
    <path d="M132.747,117.241c5.765,0,14.563-3.956,18.616-8.368c5.548-6.042,7.219-12.919,7.151-29.423l-0.058-14.067l290.407,0.713
        c-5.424,10.956-12.065,21.715-19.278,31.285c-0.598,0-2.317-0.685-3.823-1.522c-6.836-3.802-53.454-19.196-54.545-18.01
        c-0.255,0.278-0.558,1.815-0.671,3.417c-0.188,2.659,0.501,3.226,8.055,6.619c28.843,12.951,58.013,34.96,66.693,50.322
        c1.543,2.73,3.762,6.105,4.927,7.498c2.953,3.523,6.4,2.758,10.109-2.247c3.724-5.028,4.797-13.614,2.451-19.628
        c-2.584-6.627-9.453-13.933-16.926-18.004l-6.975-3.799l8.284-8.739c15.736-16.604,30.355-25.762,47.054-29.475l5.333-1.186
        L466.338,26.51l-19.287,25.631l-131.934-0.837c0-0.46,0.95-1.485,2.108-2.273c1.162-0.79,3.008-3.638,4.102-6.331
        c2.848-7.014,1.793-11.743-3.981-17.855c-5.167-5.468-21.688-14.674-36.105-20.121c-8.871-3.351-9.092-3.378-10.965-1.339
        c-1.873,2.04-1.717,2.346,7.752,15.212c9.431,12.81,16.824,26.532,16.824,31.215v2.329l-136.913-1.104
        c-0.07-0.606-0.209-1.476-0.309-1.931c-0.747-6.734-1.197-13.502-1.782-20.254l-8.098,0.669l-2.87,12.137
        c-4.672,19.751-12.426,37.031-21.287,47.445c-8.19,9.624-11.13,19.299-7.177,23.606
        C118.529,115.012,126.565,117.241,132.747,117.241z"/>
    <path d="M497.863,453.926c0,0-6.328,1.162-11.621,1.771c-53.488,6.135-95.518,8.235-164.648,8.235
        c-92.593,0-150.715-4.537-186.435-14.549c-21.072-5.908-37.036-18.377-43.876-34.272l-2.732-6.346l-0.556-207.73l8.155-6.395
        c4.486-3.517,8.03-6.792,7.876-7.278c-0.553-1.763-29.472-28.583-30.439-28.232c-0.547,0.199-4.038,5.058-7.757,10.798
        l-6.765,10.436l-28.088,0.552l-28.089,0.551l9.016,9.771l9.016,9.771l8.486-2.245c12.449-3.293,19.834-4.607,25.896-4.607h5.386
        v208.28L0,454.15l27.968,27.782c0.589-0.797,6.647-11.381,13.463-23.516c6.816-12.139,14.04-24.721,16.056-27.961
        c4.235-6.812,10.905-13.735,12.644-13.133c0.658,0.229,6.095,8.291,12.084,17.92c12.337,19.834,13.402,21.227,20.836,27.254
        c22.951,18.607,65.076,28.838,128.873,31.293c74.453,2.68,148.922,4.115,223.418,3.92l1.873-5.76
        c3.664-11.26,17.123-22.103,33.396-26.896l6.779-2v-4.248C497.389,456.469,497.863,453.926,497.863,453.926z"/>
    <path d="M67.377,99.175c3.615,13.117,7.038,20.628,10.361,22.734c4.389,2.782,9.84,0.074,15.801-7.847
        c6.25-8.306,9.067-16.414,9.077-26.118c0.018-20.292-12.427-36.144-44.859-57.137c-7.896-5.112-24.133-14.715-24.878-14.715
        c-1.627,1.909-3.001,4.063-4.373,6.208l5.627,7.655C50.934,52.805,59.531,70.706,67.377,99.175z"/>
    <path d="M173.771,362.742l0.52-190.884l3.063-2.758l3.062-2.759l-7.109-7.678l-7.108-7.678l-3.356,3.542
        c-3.192,3.369-3.737,3.542-11.244,3.542c-6.402,0-9.319-0.623-15.48-3.311c-4.175-1.82-8.006-3.31-8.513-3.31
        c-0.549,0-0.621,11.039-0.176,27.31c0.955,34.97,0.958,91.285,0.006,111.164c-1.267,26.447-4.287,49.291-9.586,72.48
        c-3.079,13.479-3.482,16.498-2.39,17.932c0.721,0.947,1.631,1.721,2.021,1.721c1.117,0,8.793-15.195,12.104-23.961
        c5.931-15.701,10.866-37.443,12.781-56.309l0.701-6.898h17.026l-1.326,55.17c-1.423,3.031-2.515,3.168-13.619,1.717
        c-6.279-0.819-6.333-0.807-6.333,1.927c0,1.928,2.073,5.016,6.923,10.313c4.599,5.021,7.539,9.328,8.759,12.826
        c1.563,4.484,2.151,5.162,3.969,4.582c5.182-1.656,9.604-6.027,12.419-12.273L173.771,362.742z M160.092,286.059h-17.225v-55.169
        h17.225V286.059z M160.092,222.062h-17.225V169.1h17.225V222.062z"/>
    <path d="M293.07,161.867l-28.633,0.519l9.645,13.688l4.053-1.601c9.032-3.139-3.802-2.639,40.807-2.178l36.75-0.577l-9.136-9.302
        l-9.138-9.302l-15.717,8.237L293.07,161.867z"/>
    <path d="M222.14,68.533l-13.546,14.79c-10.902,11.906-16.242,16.731-27.367,24.737c-13.609,9.792-34.075,21.463-47.984,27.362
        c-8.677,3.68-8.933,3.929-7.692,7.482l0.995,2.851l11.961-3.866c26.478-8.556,46.305-17.892,73.013-34.374
        c22.589-13.94,23.673-14.466,32.708-15.858l8.12-1.25l-15.104-10.938L222.14,68.533z"/>
    <path d="M346.897,139.838c-4.937-4.418-9.556-8.035-10.266-8.035c-0.711,0-4.132,1.274-7.604,2.83
        c-6.304,2.824-6.376,2.832-36.464,3.368l-30.149,0.54l9.534,13.669L280.5,149c20.153-0.787,75.367-1.13,75.367-1.13
        L346.897,139.838z"/>
    <path d="M191.97,200.99l-7.131,5.135l3.792,7.141c2.085,3.927,4.154,7.11,4.598,7.071s2.631-0.968,4.859-2.064
        c4.674-2.301,15.125-4.473,32.423-6.736c6.687-0.875,12.5-1.596,12.919-1.602c0.418-0.005,0.76,1.944,0.76,4.333
        s0.445,5.615,0.988,7.172c1.354,3.878,2.733,3.569,7.275-1.629c3.089-3.538,3.895-5.307,3.886-8.552
        c-0.012-5.345-4.213-13.069-12.353-22.718c-6.06-7.182-6.586-7.55-9.729-6.798l-3.324,0.795l2.109,3.488
        c2.306,3.813,8.108,15.761,8.108,16.697c0,0.321-9.46,0.571-21.024,0.557l-21.024-0.027l5.573-5.173
        c9.319-8.649,25.171-25.794,30.967-33.491c3.499-4.647,7.001-8.021,9.703-9.348l4.227-2.077l-7.502-7.476
        c-4.127-4.112-7.962-7.478-8.522-7.478c-0.56-0.001-2.04,2.853-3.289,6.343c-1.25,3.49-3.177,7.958-4.286,9.931l-2.016,3.586
        h-15.214c-8.367,0-15.214-0.389-15.214-0.863c0-1.57,32.485-31.646,36.547-33.836c2.19-1.181,3.977-2.423,3.971-2.758
        c-0.01-0.471-16.511-11.646-19.253-13.038c-0.314-0.159-1.139,2.018-1.831,4.838c-4.399,17.911-17.597,37.768-28.624,43.065
        c-2.208,1.061-3.893,2.242-3.744,2.625c0.147,0.384,2.041,4.976,4.206,10.205l3.936,9.507l3.157-2.587
        c1.735-1.424,1.981-2.978,7.862-4.304c5.551-2.023,17.526-4.417,19.151-3.827c1.393,0.506-8.597,15.994-15.084,23.384
        C201.226,193.434,195.893,198.165,191.97,200.99z"/>
    <g>
        <path d="M212.273,453.381c3.344,0.342,48.484,0.586,100.309,0.541c104.205-0.092,103.413-0.051,118.041-5.967
            c5.849-2.363,13.173-7.344,13.173-8.955c0-0.326-1.924-1.367-4.281-2.314c-6.762-2.721-13.946-8.301-16.041-12.454
            c-1.045-2.07-2.46-6.722-3.145-10.333l-1.247-6.569h-7.71l-0.052,8.836c-0.064,11.17-0.775,16.463-2.543,18.949
            c-0.769,1.08-3.727,3.758-7.037,3.852c-75.582,2.135-45.149,2.668-178.322,1.857l-3.958-2.023
            c-7.031-3.596-8.162-5.832-8.495-16.811l-0.294-9.677l7.403-9.295c-0.404-0.127-7.347-2.629-15.428-5.555l-14.692-5.318
            l-0.294,17.783c-0.404,24.496,0.977,30.943,7.974,37.199C199.686,450.748,204.608,452.6,212.273,453.381z"/>
        <path d="M154.256,404.033c-8.408,11.227-12.161,14.928-23.174,22.85c-9.769,7.023-12.531,9.717-12.531,12.219
            c0,2.013,2.844,4.125,7.092,5.271c5.889,1.586,15.512,0.643,20.592-2.021c11.565-6.061,17.982-18.053,19.518-36.479l0.688-8.248
            l-2.993-0.937C160.487,395.766,160.388,395.846,154.256,404.033z"/>
        <path d="M467.429,427.342c7.128,6.679,13.961,12.64,15.182,13.246c2.935,1.459,3.889,1.433,6.477-0.188
            c4.783-2.996,7.222-17.277,3.925-22.98c-2.907-5.024-19.268-12.119-49.51-21.471l-6.883-2.13l-1.896,2.789l-1.896,2.789
            l10.818,7.902C449.596,411.645,460.298,420.664,467.429,427.342z"/>
        <path d="M269.754,387.078c23.155,8.477,43.153,21.201,61.019,38.826c4.429,4.369,9.442,8.715,11.146,9.653
            c5.188,2.869,9.702,1.068,12.854-5.127c3.214-6.315,1.988-12.452-3.85-19.299c-7.554-8.856-35.523-19.508-81.013-30.853
            c-5.78-1.442-6.18-1.364-7.217,1.421C261.796,384.111,261.941,384.221,269.754,387.078z"/>
    </g>
    <g>
        <path d="M467.412,353.047c-2.155,3.582-4.95,3.83-15.26,1.361c-8.745-2.096-8.292-2.172-8.292,1.41
            c0.002,2.524,0.918,3.666,4.922,6.123c7.375,4.526,13.388,10.608,15.398,15.578l1.795,4.434l3.04-1.924
            c4.878-3.088,12.663-13.078,14.016-17.979c0.923-3.36,1.241-28.937,1.241-99.608c0-94.833,0.008-95.104,2.189-98.953
            c1.205-2.123,2.022-4.032,1.813-4.239c-1.136-1.142-19.828-13.102-20.033-12.818c0.024,38.464,2.318,76.997,1.136,115.494
            C469.258,344.197,469.128,350.195,467.412,353.047z"/>
        <path d="M460.258,187.415c-0.833-0.828-19.634-12.998-20.08-12.998c-0.276,0-0.206,1.396,0.158,3.104
            c0.88,4.141,0.673,134.569,0.673,134.569l-1.222,13.625l4.368-2.914c2.401-1.604,6.139-4.033,8.304-5.404
            c3.392-2.143,3.833-2.873,3.206-5.307c-2.539-38.09-0.279-76.467-1.546-114.606l3.234-4.867
            C459.136,189.939,460.443,187.599,460.258,187.415z"/>
    </g>
    <g>
        <path d="M324.872,336.477c0.914,3.049,2.071,6.414,2.574,7.476c0.503,1.063,1.563,1.934,2.354,1.934
            c1.909,0,6.542-8.731,7.288-13.739c0.53-3.578,0.188-4.396-3.511-8.222c-7.599-7.87-18.464-13.133-18.464-8.938
            c0,0.475,1.821,4.258,4.047,8.406C321.389,327.535,323.957,333.424,324.872,336.477z"/>
        <path d="M305.599,322.059c-4.9-3.918-6.319-4.567-7.93-3.629c-1.078,0.629-1.729,1.725-1.446,2.437
            c5.487,13.84,7.747,19.838,7.747,20.557c0,0.486,0.688,2.681,1.534,4.879c0.843,2.197,2.206,3.996,3.025,3.996
            c2.134,0,6.729-8.422,7.35-13.467C316.503,331.787,314.914,329.504,305.599,322.059z"/>
        <path d="M267.803,322.389l-2.938,0.803c-1.614,0.443-2.983,0.89-3.041,0.99c-0.06,0.103-1.337,3.164-2.841,6.805
            c-1.502,3.642-5.028,10.438-7.834,15.105c-2.808,4.664-4.946,9.367-4.754,10.451c0.192,1.086,1.484,2.6,2.874,3.363
            c3.453,1.902,5.027,1.771,8.807-0.736c5.485-3.646,8.052-11.264,9.083-26.965L267.803,322.389z"/>
        <path d="M292.098,349.443c5.434-10.875,4.582-14.133-6.117-23.508c-6.394-5.601-7.758-6.367-9.508-5.349
            c-1.121,0.654-1.82,1.772-1.552,2.483c0.871,2.291,7.397,20.984,9.218,26.396C286.454,356.352,288.646,356.346,292.098,349.443z"
            />
        <path d="M358.401,313.439c0.123-1.76,1.138-4.265,2.258-5.562l2.036-2.36l-7.324-6.765l-7.323-6.762l-6.177,6.446h-29.793v-8.83
            h37.606l-5.834-7.723c-3.209-4.248-6.22-7.723-6.688-7.723c-0.467,0-2.638,0.994-4.822,2.205
            c-6.396,3.053-13.453,2.074-20.265,2.207v-9.93h37.669l-8.936-11.33l-3.434-4.158l-4.488,2.227
            c-3.313,1.645-6.624,2.227-12.65,2.227h-8.161v-9.929h23.938h23.941l-10.257-8.925l-10.26-8.924l-5.087,3.407l-5.085,3.409
            h-28.884h-28.885l-6.724-3.319c-3.697-1.827-6.853-3.181-7.01-3.009c-0.158,0.172,0.092,4.273,0.555,9.113
            c1.08,11.3,1.058,51.577-0.039,67.229c-0.467,6.647-0.75,12.157-0.631,12.248c0.119,0.088,4.18-0.32,9.025-0.906l8.811-1.063
            l0.31-3.459l0.31-3.457h32.93h32.93l-0.027,11.033c-0.035,14.659-2.152,22.293-7.934,28.588
            c-5.641,6.143-10.338,7.366-28.119,7.342c-7.742-0.01-14.074,0.404-14.074,0.924c0,1.494,2.207,2.934,6.586,4.293
            c7.826,2.428,15.965,9.639,17.98,15.93c0.399,1.252,9.794-1.801,15.963-5.188c8.899-4.885,15.709-11.869,19.164-19.662
            c2.923-6.592,6.166-20.684,6.166-26.797C357.673,324.498,358.316,314.664,358.401,313.439z M275.777,251.361l0.33-3.128h21.277
            v8.828l-10.402,0.314C275.643,257.719,275.139,257.449,275.777,251.361z M297.893,298.439h-22.291v-8.83h22.291V298.439z
             M297.386,278.023l-21.075-0.148c-0.968-2.947-0.68-6.131-0.709-9.23h22.408L297.386,278.023z"/>
    </g>
    <path d="M365.116,315.664c1.356-0.563,2.697-1.021,2.978-1.021c0.038,0.376,0.063,57.187,0.063,57.187l3.227,4.437l3.226,4.436
        l7.71-6.021c4.24-3.313,10.413-7.842,13.716-10.063c4.644-3.121,5.892-4.514,5.503-6.133c-0.314-1.307,1.66,0.127,5.251,3.818
        c3.164,3.254,8.144,7.801,11.064,10.108c5.021,3.969,5.405,4.092,7.052,2.301c2.273-2.476,7.671-4.899,10.908-4.899
        c1.841,0,2.566-0.59,2.566-2.082c0-1.574-2.016-2.967-8.248-5.701c-13.227-5.807-23.164-13.982-23.164-19.059
        c0-1.607,8.525-6.173,15.959-8.546c2.367-0.756,4.306-1.53,4.306-1.727s-2.229-4.16-4.956-8.813l-4.958-8.462l-4.235,7.304
        c-2.328,4.018-5.628,8.578-7.33,10.139c-3.631,3.326-3.104,3.846-9.88-9.668l-4.288-8.553h21.935
        c24.969,0,23.409,1.069,14.507-9.955l-4.778-5.918l-4.19,4.653l-4.188,4.654l-15.856-0.304l-15.854-0.305v-15.445l21.001-0.299
        l21.001-0.299l-4.147-7.426c-6.226-11.145-5.641-10.877-10.191-4.654l-4.025,5.506h-23.713l0.156-16.187
        c0,0,9.811-0.366,21.283-0.366h20.855l-2.92-4.137c-1.605-2.275-3.707-5.504-4.668-7.172c-0.961-1.67-2.207-3.035-2.771-3.035
        c-3.22,1.875-5.566,5.064-8.179,7.793l-23.602,0.083l-0.079-16.15l23.022-0.296l23.022-0.297l-5.762-8.254
        c-3.168-4.541-6.071-8.255-6.449-8.255s-2.347,2.371-4.377,5.271l-3.69,5.271l-27.793-0.132l-6.334-4.694l-6.332-4.694v78.42
        h-6.791h-6.793l3.885,4.332C362.113,316.086,362.989,316.543,365.116,315.664z M383.404,314.583c0,0,8.866,27.05,12.348,32.667
        c1.746,2.82,3.274,5.615,3.396,6.215c0.18,0.891-15.211,8.006-15.609,7.213C383.383,356.627,383.404,314.583,383.404,314.583z"/>
</g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Damnit! its not in unicode :/

Comment: "must exactly reproduce this SVG in every way" - vague and impossible. At the very least shifting an image half a pixel results in different anti-aliasing. Also, I'm pretty sure the SVG spec doesn't mandate any antialiasing algorithm. Also, this essentially boils down to compressing the SVG file (which you should inline; SE doesn't like external resources) and implementing a subset of a SVG renderer. Or... do you want us to output a SVG file with one parameter tweakable (boiling this challenge to a XML compression task)?

Comment: @JanDvorak Well as I progressed with the challenge I realised that it was going to boil down to who can compress the XML the best. I will remove the size parameter though.

Comment: You should also inline the desired output. Wikipedia isn't down too often, but they might change the file.

Comment: Umm... what if Pastebin goes down?

Comment: Also, I assume you don't require the whitespace to be followed? If so, you should specify that.

Comment: @JanDvorak I'll put it in the question later. I'm on my phone so adding four spaces behind each line is a bugger. ;)

Comment: can we "golf the svg", or do we just have to golf a program that outputs this svg file? Also, can you confirm that the shortest program "in bytes" wins?

Comment: @BetaDecay why aren't you happy with the indentation as it was already?

Comment: @xem That's the default if nothing is specified (as stated in the tag wiki for [tag:code-golf]).

Comment: @JanDvorak To format it as code, because I can't do Ctrl-K, I have to put four spaces behind each line.

Comment: @xem You must write a program

Comment: FYT, it's just the most complex character IN USE: http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_character#Rare_and_complex_characters

Comment: This would be much more fun if the challenge was to make a readable version of this character instead of just copying an SVG file. Not much code-golf in that, is there?

Comment: @xem the other "more complex" characters on that article all involve a lot of repetition. I wouldn't call them more complex at all.

Comment: @sanchises That's a nice idea, but would need some specification in practice. My knowledge of Chinese is limited, but I count 12 radical elements in that character. It should be possible to do some kind of montage of 12 unicode characters. Would that be acceptable?  If it has to be a line drawing those who know Chinese well enough could start to argue about what simplifications are acceptable. Ultimately the smallest representation of this character by bytes is probably the pînyîn `biáng`.

Comment: Not forbidding built-in compressing algorithms makes this question moot. There is no challenge in invoking zlib.decompress.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## PHP - 8559 bytes

```
<?=bzdecompress(base64_decode('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'));
```

Comment: Found this old question through the meta article [Longest Code Golf Answer ever](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/9805/longest-code-golf-answer-ever), but with Phar and bzip2 it can be golfed down to 6557 bytes: http://mehr.it/golf/biang.phar - It's not so much a golfing challenge as a compression challenge. ;)

Answer (score 8):

## perl 17055

```
print '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 15.0.2, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg version="1.1" id="svg2" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="500px" height="500px"
     viewBox="0 0 500 500" enable-background="new 0 0 500 500" xml:space="preserve">
<g>
    <path d="M408.997,122.382l3.629-2.032l-10.012-6.497l-10.009-6.497l-2.195,7.083c-2.958,9.552-8.487,20.773-14.003,28.416
        c-4.355,6.038-13.775,14.106-16.467,14.106c-1.68,0-1.755-0.338,1.861,8.345c1.729,4.151,3.555,8.729,4.06,10.174l0.918,2.628
        l3.079-2.823c1.695-1.553,2.253-3.035,8.304-4.512c6.57-2.126,17.534-4.232,19.088-3.667c0.664,0.242-2.23,5.356-6.649,11.744
        c-7.984,11.543-16.75,20.515-23.942,24.513l-4.021,2.23l2.822,5.478c1.553,3.012,3.536,6.505,4.409,7.765
        c1.581,2.29,1.583,2.29,5.064,0.121c4.438-2.765,10.479-4.206,26.281-6.271c6.966-0.912,14.321-1.902,16.349-2.202
        c3.173-0.472,3.769-0.204,4.293,1.928c0.602,3.25,0.421,6.658,1.686,9.72c1.433,2.916,2.298,2.712,6.408-1.512
        c6.831-7.014,5.967-13.847-3.337-26.405c-8.965-12.096-10.583-13.513-14.101-12.321l-2.938,0.995l4.938,9.333
        c2.719,5.134,4.939,9.727,4.939,10.207c-11.883,3.042-30.03,1.979-40.493-0.616c11.232-11.183,22.685-22.159,32.729-34.656
        c4.926-6.111,10.282-11.712,11.905-12.445c1.625-0.731,2.952-1.666,2.952-2.075c0-1.163-13.91-14.435-15.127-14.435
        c-0.598,0-1.084,0.441-1.084,0.98c0,0.54-1.685,5.007-3.74,9.931l-3.743,8.95h-15.509c-8.531,0-15.511-0.396-15.511-0.879
        C371.832,155.722,405.104,124.561,408.997,122.382z"/>
    <path d="M258.98,130.742c0.053,0.014,1.647-0.792,3.545-1.79c7.975-3.285-2.358-2.285,55.517-2.333l52.069-0.518l-10.669-10.107
        c-5.87-5.56-11.147-10.108-11.729-10.108s-5.587,2.333-11.124,5.184c-9.552,4.919-10.469,5.183-18.048,5.167l-7.983-0.018
        l3.958-2.316c2.174-1.272,4.808-3.489,5.847-4.924c5.623-7.761-5.982-19.346-28.117-28.067c-8.884-3.5-9.777-3.59-13.149-1.33
        l-2.516,1.685l8.925,8.95c4.908,4.921,10.896,11.744,13.305,15.16c2.41,3.415,5.583,7.258,7.053,8.539l2.671,2.327l-65.431,0.01
        L258.98,130.742z"/>
    <path d="M186.128,315.664c1.356-0.563,2.697-1.021,2.978-1.021c0.038,0.376,0.062,57.187,0.062,57.187l3.226,4.437l3.226,4.436
        l7.71-6.021c4.24-3.313,10.413-7.842,13.716-10.063c4.644-3.121,5.891-4.514,5.503-6.133c-0.314-1.307,1.66,0.127,5.251,3.818
        c3.164,3.254,8.144,7.801,11.064,10.108c5.021,3.969,5.406,4.092,7.052,2.301c2.273-2.476,7.671-4.899,10.908-4.899
        c1.841,0,2.566-0.59,2.566-2.082c0-1.574-2.016-2.967-8.248-5.701c-13.227-5.807-23.164-13.982-23.164-19.059
        c0-1.607,8.525-6.173,15.958-8.546c2.368-0.756,4.306-1.53,4.306-1.727s-2.229-4.16-4.956-8.813l-4.958-8.462l-4.235,7.304
        c-2.329,4.018-5.628,8.578-7.331,10.139c-3.63,3.326-3.103,3.846-9.879-9.668l-4.288-8.553h21.934
        c24.969,0,23.409,1.069,14.507-9.955l-4.778-5.918l-4.19,4.653l-4.189,4.654l-15.856-0.304l-15.855-0.305v-15.445l21.001-0.299
        l21.001-0.299l-4.147-7.426c-6.226-11.145-5.641-10.877-10.192-4.654l-4.025,5.506h-23.713l0.156-16.187
        c0,0,9.811-0.366,21.283-0.366h20.856l-2.92-4.137c-1.606-2.275-3.707-5.504-4.668-7.172c-0.961-1.67-2.208-3.035-2.771-3.035
        c-3.22,1.875-5.566,5.064-8.179,7.793l-23.601,0.083l-0.079-16.15l23.023-0.296l23.022-0.297l-5.762-8.254
        c-3.168-4.541-6.071-8.255-6.449-8.255s-2.347,2.371-4.377,5.271l-3.691,5.271l-27.793-0.132l-6.333-4.694l-6.333-4.694v78.42
        h-6.791h-6.792l3.884,4.332C183.125,316.086,184.001,316.543,186.128,315.664z M204.417,314.583c0,0,8.866,27.05,12.347,32.667
        c1.747,2.82,3.275,5.615,3.396,6.215c0.18,0.891-15.211,8.006-15.609,7.213C204.395,356.627,204.417,314.583,204.417,314.583z"/>
    <path d="M261.965,181.771c1.221,9.539,1.402,12.767,1.438,25.451c0.021,7.555,0.445,13.736,0.945,13.736l17.965-4.775l46.482-0.927
        l0.329,2.951c0.243,2.176,0.775,2.827,2.026,2.48c17.15-4.759,18.48-5.351,17.973-8.02c-0.273-1.428-0.788-4.786-1.147-7.462
        l-0.65-4.867l5.256-3.307c4.265-2.687,4.999-3.544,3.904-4.574c-5.08-4.773-18.053-15.041-19.002-15.041
        c-0.636,0-3.405,1.167-6.154,2.591c-4.897,2.54-5.468,2.592-28.083,2.591c-21.454,0-30.73-0.863-40.001-3.72
        C261.818,178.44,261.602,178.93,261.965,181.771z M282.587,194.416l46.771-0.173l-0.059,10.129h-46.714L282.587,194.416
        L282.587,194.416z"/>
    <path d="M132.747,117.241c5.765,0,14.563-3.956,18.616-8.368c5.548-6.042,7.219-12.919,7.151-29.423l-0.058-14.067l290.407,0.713
        c-5.424,10.956-12.065,21.715-19.278,31.285c-0.598,0-2.317-0.685-3.823-1.522c-6.836-3.802-53.454-19.196-54.545-18.01
        c-0.255,0.278-0.558,1.815-0.671,3.417c-0.188,2.659,0.501,3.226,8.055,6.619c28.843,12.951,58.013,34.96,66.693,50.322
        c1.543,2.73,3.762,6.105,4.927,7.498c2.953,3.523,6.4,2.758,10.109-2.247c3.724-5.028,4.797-13.614,2.451-19.628
        c-2.584-6.627-9.453-13.933-16.926-18.004l-6.975-3.799l8.284-8.739c15.736-16.604,30.355-25.762,47.054-29.475l5.333-1.186
        L466.338,26.51l-19.287,25.631l-131.934-0.837c0-0.46,0.95-1.485,2.108-2.273c1.162-0.79,3.008-3.638,4.102-6.331
        c2.848-7.014,1.793-11.743-3.981-17.855c-5.167-5.468-21.688-14.674-36.105-20.121c-8.871-3.351-9.092-3.378-10.965-1.339
        c-1.873,2.04-1.717,2.346,7.752,15.212c9.431,12.81,16.824,26.532,16.824,31.215v2.329l-136.913-1.104
        c-0.07-0.606-0.209-1.476-0.309-1.931c-0.747-6.734-1.197-13.502-1.782-20.254l-8.098,0.669l-2.87,12.137
        c-4.672,19.751-12.426,37.031-21.287,47.445c-8.19,9.624-11.13,19.299-7.177,23.606
        C118.529,115.012,126.565,117.241,132.747,117.241z"/>
    <path d="M497.863,453.926c0,0-6.328,1.162-11.621,1.771c-53.488,6.135-95.518,8.235-164.648,8.235
        c-92.593,0-150.715-4.537-186.435-14.549c-21.072-5.908-37.036-18.377-43.876-34.272l-2.732-6.346l-0.556-207.73l8.155-6.395
        c4.486-3.517,8.03-6.792,7.876-7.278c-0.553-1.763-29.472-28.583-30.439-28.232c-0.547,0.199-4.038,5.058-7.757,10.798
        l-6.765,10.436l-28.088,0.552l-28.089,0.551l9.016,9.771l9.016,9.771l8.486-2.245c12.449-3.293,19.834-4.607,25.896-4.607h5.386
        v208.28L0,454.15l27.968,27.782c0.589-0.797,6.647-11.381,13.463-23.516c6.816-12.139,14.04-24.721,16.056-27.961
        c4.235-6.812,10.905-13.735,12.644-13.133c0.658,0.229,6.095,8.291,12.084,17.92c12.337,19.834,13.402,21.227,20.836,27.254
        c22.951,18.607,65.076,28.838,128.873,31.293c74.453,2.68,148.922,4.115,223.418,3.92l1.873-5.76
        c3.664-11.26,17.123-22.103,33.396-26.896l6.779-2v-4.248C497.389,456.469,497.863,453.926,497.863,453.926z"/>
    <path d="M67.377,99.175c3.615,13.117,7.038,20.628,10.361,22.734c4.389,2.782,9.84,0.074,15.801-7.847
        c6.25-8.306,9.067-16.414,9.077-26.118c0.018-20.292-12.427-36.144-44.859-57.137c-7.896-5.112-24.133-14.715-24.878-14.715
        c-1.627,1.909-3.001,4.063-4.373,6.208l5.627,7.655C50.934,52.805,59.531,70.706,67.377,99.175z"/>
    <path d="M173.771,362.742l0.52-190.884l3.063-2.758l3.062-2.759l-7.109-7.678l-7.108-7.678l-3.356,3.542
        c-3.192,3.369-3.737,3.542-11.244,3.542c-6.402,0-9.319-0.623-15.48-3.311c-4.175-1.82-8.006-3.31-8.513-3.31
        c-0.549,0-0.621,11.039-0.176,27.31c0.955,34.97,0.958,91.285,0.006,111.164c-1.267,26.447-4.287,49.291-9.586,72.48
        c-3.079,13.479-3.482,16.498-2.39,17.932c0.721,0.947,1.631,1.721,2.021,1.721c1.117,0,8.793-15.195,12.104-23.961
        c5.931-15.701,10.866-37.443,12.781-56.309l0.701-6.898h17.026l-1.326,55.17c-1.423,3.031-2.515,3.168-13.619,1.717
        c-6.279-0.819-6.333-0.807-6.333,1.927c0,1.928,2.073,5.016,6.923,10.313c4.599,5.021,7.539,9.328,8.759,12.826
        c1.563,4.484,2.151,5.162,3.969,4.582c5.182-1.656,9.604-6.027,12.419-12.273L173.771,362.742z M160.092,286.059h-17.225v-55.169
        h17.225V286.059z M160.092,222.062h-17.225V169.1h17.225V222.062z"/>
    <path d="M293.07,161.867l-28.633,0.519l9.645,13.688l4.053-1.601c9.032-3.139-3.802-2.639,40.807-2.178l36.75-0.577l-9.136-9.302
        l-9.138-9.302l-15.717,8.237L293.07,161.867z"/>
    <path d="M222.14,68.533l-13.546,14.79c-10.902,11.906-16.242,16.731-27.367,24.737c-13.609,9.792-34.075,21.463-47.984,27.362
        c-8.677,3.68-8.933,3.929-7.692,7.482l0.995,2.851l11.961-3.866c26.478-8.556,46.305-17.892,73.013-34.374
        c22.589-13.94,23.673-14.466,32.708-15.858l8.12-1.25l-15.104-10.938L222.14,68.533z"/>
    <path d="M346.897,139.838c-4.937-4.418-9.556-8.035-10.266-8.035c-0.711,0-4.132,1.274-7.604,2.83
        c-6.304,2.824-6.376,2.832-36.464,3.368l-30.149,0.54l9.534,13.669L280.5,149c20.153-0.787,75.367-1.13,75.367-1.13
        L346.897,139.838z"/>
    <path d="M191.97,200.99l-7.131,5.135l3.792,7.141c2.085,3.927,4.154,7.11,4.598,7.071s2.631-0.968,4.859-2.064
        c4.674-2.301,15.125-4.473,32.423-6.736c6.687-0.875,12.5-1.596,12.919-1.602c0.418-0.005,0.76,1.944,0.76,4.333
        s0.445,5.615,0.988,7.172c1.354,3.878,2.733,3.569,7.275-1.629c3.089-3.538,3.895-5.307,3.886-8.552
        c-0.012-5.345-4.213-13.069-12.353-22.718c-6.06-7.182-6.586-7.55-9.729-6.798l-3.324,0.795l2.109,3.488
        c2.306,3.813,8.108,15.761,8.108,16.697c0,0.321-9.46,0.571-21.024,0.557l-21.024-0.027l5.573-5.173
        c9.319-8.649,25.171-25.794,30.967-33.491c3.499-4.647,7.001-8.021,9.703-9.348l4.227-2.077l-7.502-7.476
        c-4.127-4.112-7.962-7.478-8.522-7.478c-0.56-0.001-2.04,2.853-3.289,6.343c-1.25,3.49-3.177,7.958-4.286,9.931l-2.016,3.586
        h-15.214c-8.367,0-15.214-0.389-15.214-0.863c0-1.57,32.485-31.646,36.547-33.836c2.19-1.181,3.977-2.423,3.971-2.758
        c-0.01-0.471-16.511-11.646-19.253-13.038c-0.314-0.159-1.139,2.018-1.831,4.838c-4.399,17.911-17.597,37.768-28.624,43.065
        c-2.208,1.061-3.893,2.242-3.744,2.625c0.147,0.384,2.041,4.976,4.206,10.205l3.936,9.507l3.157-2.587
        c1.735-1.424,1.981-2.978,7.862-4.304c5.551-2.023,17.526-4.417,19.151-3.827c1.393,0.506-8.597,15.994-15.084,23.384
        C201.226,193.434,195.893,198.165,191.97,200.99z"/>
    <g>
        <path d="M212.273,453.381c3.344,0.342,48.484,0.586,100.309,0.541c104.205-0.092,103.413-0.051,118.041-5.967
            c5.849-2.363,13.173-7.344,13.173-8.955c0-0.326-1.924-1.367-4.281-2.314c-6.762-2.721-13.946-8.301-16.041-12.454
            c-1.045-2.07-2.46-6.722-3.145-10.333l-1.247-6.569h-7.71l-0.052,8.836c-0.064,11.17-0.775,16.463-2.543,18.949
            c-0.769,1.08-3.727,3.758-7.037,3.852c-75.582,2.135-45.149,2.668-178.322,1.857l-3.958-2.023
            c-7.031-3.596-8.162-5.832-8.495-16.811l-0.294-9.677l7.403-9.295c-0.404-0.127-7.347-2.629-15.428-5.555l-14.692-5.318
            l-0.294,17.783c-0.404,24.496,0.977,30.943,7.974,37.199C199.686,450.748,204.608,452.6,212.273,453.381z"/>
        <path d="M154.256,404.033c-8.408,11.227-12.161,14.928-23.174,22.85c-9.769,7.023-12.531,9.717-12.531,12.219
            c0,2.013,2.844,4.125,7.092,5.271c5.889,1.586,15.512,0.643,20.592-2.021c11.565-6.061,17.982-18.053,19.518-36.479l0.688-8.248
            l-2.993-0.937C160.487,395.766,160.388,395.846,154.256,404.033z"/>
        <path d="M467.429,427.342c7.128,6.679,13.961,12.64,15.182,13.246c2.935,1.459,3.889,1.433,6.477-0.188
            c4.783-2.996,7.222-17.277,3.925-22.98c-2.907-5.024-19.268-12.119-49.51-21.471l-6.883-2.13l-1.896,2.789l-1.896,2.789
            l10.818,7.902C449.596,411.645,460.298,420.664,467.429,427.342z"/>
        <path d="M269.754,387.078c23.155,8.477,43.153,21.201,61.019,38.826c4.429,4.369,9.442,8.715,11.146,9.653
            c5.188,2.869,9.702,1.068,12.854-5.127c3.214-6.315,1.988-12.452-3.85-19.299c-7.554-8.856-35.523-19.508-81.013-30.853
            c-5.78-1.442-6.18-1.364-7.217,1.421C261.796,384.111,261.941,384.221,269.754,387.078z"/>
    </g>
    <g>
        <path d="M467.412,353.047c-2.155,3.582-4.95,3.83-15.26,1.361c-8.745-2.096-8.292-2.172-8.292,1.41
            c0.002,2.524,0.918,3.666,4.922,6.123c7.375,4.526,13.388,10.608,15.398,15.578l1.795,4.434l3.04-1.924
            c4.878-3.088,12.663-13.078,14.016-17.979c0.923-3.36,1.241-28.937,1.241-99.608c0-94.833,0.008-95.104,2.189-98.953
            c1.205-2.123,2.022-4.032,1.813-4.239c-1.136-1.142-19.828-13.102-20.033-12.818c0.024,38.464,2.318,76.997,1.136,115.494
            C469.258,344.197,469.128,350.195,467.412,353.047z"/>
        <path d="M460.258,187.415c-0.833-0.828-19.634-12.998-20.08-12.998c-0.276,0-0.206,1.396,0.158,3.104
            c0.88,4.141,0.673,134.569,0.673,134.569l-1.222,13.625l4.368-2.914c2.401-1.604,6.139-4.033,8.304-5.404
            c3.392-2.143,3.833-2.873,3.206-5.307c-2.539-38.09-0.279-76.467-1.546-114.606l3.234-4.867
            C459.136,189.939,460.443,187.599,460.258,187.415z"/>
    </g>
    <g>
        <path d="M324.872,336.477c0.914,3.049,2.071,6.414,2.574,7.476c0.503,1.063,1.563,1.934,2.354,1.934
            c1.909,0,6.542-8.731,7.288-13.739c0.53-3.578,0.188-4.396-3.511-8.222c-7.599-7.87-18.464-13.133-18.464-8.938
            c0,0.475,1.821,4.258,4.047,8.406C321.389,327.535,323.957,333.424,324.872,336.477z"/>
        <path d="M305.599,322.059c-4.9-3.918-6.319-4.567-7.93-3.629c-1.078,0.629-1.729,1.725-1.446,2.437
            c5.487,13.84,7.747,19.838,7.747,20.557c0,0.486,0.688,2.681,1.534,4.879c0.843,2.197,2.206,3.996,3.025,3.996
            c2.134,0,6.729-8.422,7.35-13.467C316.503,331.787,314.914,329.504,305.599,322.059z"/>
        <path d="M267.803,322.389l-2.938,0.803c-1.614,0.443-2.983,0.89-3.041,0.99c-0.06,0.103-1.337,3.164-2.841,6.805
            c-1.502,3.642-5.028,10.438-7.834,15.105c-2.808,4.664-4.946,9.367-4.754,10.451c0.192,1.086,1.484,2.6,2.874,3.363
            c3.453,1.902,5.027,1.771,8.807-0.736c5.485-3.646,8.052-11.264,9.083-26.965L267.803,322.389z"/>
        <path d="M292.098,349.443c5.434-10.875,4.582-14.133-6.117-23.508c-6.394-5.601-7.758-6.367-9.508-5.349
            c-1.121,0.654-1.82,1.772-1.552,2.483c0.871,2.291,7.397,20.984,9.218,26.396C286.454,356.352,288.646,356.346,292.098,349.443z"
            />
        <path d="M358.401,313.439c0.123-1.76,1.138-4.265,2.258-5.562l2.036-2.36l-7.324-6.765l-7.323-6.762l-6.177,6.446h-29.793v-8.83
            h37.606l-5.834-7.723c-3.209-4.248-6.22-7.723-6.688-7.723c-0.467,0-2.638,0.994-4.822,2.205
            c-6.396,3.053-13.453,2.074-20.265,2.207v-9.93h37.669l-8.936-11.33l-3.434-4.158l-4.488,2.227
            c-3.313,1.645-6.624,2.227-12.65,2.227h-8.161v-9.929h23.938h23.941l-10.257-8.925l-10.26-8.924l-5.087,3.407l-5.085,3.409
            h-28.884h-28.885l-6.724-3.319c-3.697-1.827-6.853-3.181-7.01-3.009c-0.158,0.172,0.092,4.273,0.555,9.113
            c1.08,11.3,1.058,51.577-0.039,67.229c-0.467,6.647-0.75,12.157-0.631,12.248c0.119,0.088,4.18-0.32,9.025-0.906l8.811-1.063
            l0.31-3.459l0.31-3.457h32.93h32.93l-0.027,11.033c-0.035,14.659-2.152,22.293-7.934,28.588
            c-5.641,6.143-10.338,7.366-28.119,7.342c-7.742-0.01-14.074,0.404-14.074,0.924c0,1.494,2.207,2.934,6.586,4.293
            c7.826,2.428,15.965,9.639,17.98,15.93c0.399,1.252,9.794-1.801,15.963-5.188c8.899-4.885,15.709-11.869,19.164-19.662
            c2.923-6.592,6.166-20.684,6.166-26.797C357.673,324.498,358.316,314.664,358.401,313.439z M275.777,251.361l0.33-3.128h21.277
            v8.828l-10.402,0.314C275.643,257.719,275.139,257.449,275.777,251.361z M297.893,298.439h-22.291v-8.83h22.291V298.439z
             M297.386,278.023l-21.075-0.148c-0.968-2.947-0.68-6.131-0.709-9.23h22.408L297.386,278.023z"/>
    </g>
    <path d="M365.116,315.664c1.356-0.563,2.697-1.021,2.978-1.021c0.038,0.376,0.063,57.187,0.063,57.187l3.227,4.437l3.226,4.436
        l7.71-6.021c4.24-3.313,10.413-7.842,13.716-10.063c4.644-3.121,5.892-4.514,5.503-6.133c-0.314-1.307,1.66,0.127,5.251,3.818
        c3.164,3.254,8.144,7.801,11.064,10.108c5.021,3.969,5.405,4.092,7.052,2.301c2.273-2.476,7.671-4.899,10.908-4.899
        c1.841,0,2.566-0.59,2.566-2.082c0-1.574-2.016-2.967-8.248-5.701c-13.227-5.807-23.164-13.982-23.164-19.059
        c0-1.607,8.525-6.173,15.959-8.546c2.367-0.756,4.306-1.53,4.306-1.727s-2.229-4.16-4.956-8.813l-4.958-8.462l-4.235,7.304
        c-2.328,4.018-5.628,8.578-7.33,10.139c-3.631,3.326-3.104,3.846-9.88-9.668l-4.288-8.553h21.935
        c24.969,0,23.409,1.069,14.507-9.955l-4.778-5.918l-4.19,4.653l-4.188,4.654l-15.856-0.304l-15.854-0.305v-15.445l21.001-0.299
        l21.001-0.299l-4.147-7.426c-6.226-11.145-5.641-10.877-10.191-4.654l-4.025,5.506h-23.713l0.156-16.187
        c0,0,9.811-0.366,21.283-0.366h20.855l-2.92-4.137c-1.605-2.275-3.707-5.504-4.668-7.172c-0.961-1.67-2.207-3.035-2.771-3.035
        c-3.22,1.875-5.566,5.064-8.179,7.793l-23.602,0.083l-0.079-16.15l23.022-0.296l23.022-0.297l-5.762-8.254
        c-3.168-4.541-6.071-8.255-6.449-8.255s-2.347,2.371-4.377,5.271l-3.69,5.271l-27.793-0.132l-6.334-4.694l-6.332-4.694v78.42
        h-6.791h-6.793l3.885,4.332C362.113,316.086,362.989,316.543,365.116,315.664z M383.404,314.583c0,0,8.866,27.05,12.348,32.667
        c1.746,2.82,3.274,5.615,3.396,6.215c0.18,0.891-15.211,8.006-15.609,7.213C383.383,356.627,383.404,314.583,383.404,314.583z"/>
</g>
</svg>'
```

kolmogorov who?

Comment: Ahem... Isn't that the exact text from the question with a `print` stuck on the beginning? You can save some characters by removing unnecesary whitespace and using a standard compression program ;-D  3 upvotes means either 3 people didn't notice, or they're the same 3 people that downvoted the question..

Comment: @steveverrill first start with normal code, then we optimize! XD

Comment: @Compass I'm still waiting for the Brainfuck answer.

Comment: @steveverrill I can write this using calligraphy and ink if you wish.

Comment: @steveverrill not just a print, also a pair of single quotes!

Comment: @Compass I already upvoted your answer. Regarding calligraphy, I don't think it would pass this test: http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/2028/15599 . Ironically a simple monochrome .BMP file would only be 420*392/8=20580 bytes. For another idea, see my comment on the question.

Comment: @steveverrill I know! But I know more about calligraphy than I do about BF, and I don't know much about calligraphy!

Comment: This doesn't actually output an SVG file does it? It just prints the source.

Comment: @BetaDecay clarify the difference?

Comment: By running this code, a .svg file is not created. For that, I'd have to run `perl program.pl > image.svg`.

Comment: @BetaDecay you're using a weird interpretation of "output a file" that contradicts every other solution here

Comment: @Sparr Ah okay. I'll keep it as you've interpreted it

Answer (score 6):

## HTML/JavaScript 14184 Bytes

Using [Obfuscatweet] we can get 7146 chars! (http://xem.github.io/obfuscatweet/):

```
document.write(unescape(escape('').replace(/uD./g,'')))
```

#### Original HTML/JS

[Demo](http://c99.nl/f/115183.html)

Original HTML is <s>15039</s> 14182 <s>and pushes me over the size limit</s>. The entire SVG has been reduced in complexity using parsing and substring searches replaced with the letters D and so on.

```
<script>
function d(a){document.write(a)};
function r(a,b,c){return a.replace(b,c)};
D='<g>';
E='</g>';
F='"/>';
G='<path d="M';
H=',4.092,7.052,2.301c2.273-2.476,7.671-4.899,10.908-4.899c1.841,0,2.566-0.59,2.566-2.082c0-1.574-2.016-2.967-8.248-5.701c-13.227-5.807-23.164-13.982-23.164-19.059c0-1.607,8.525-6.173,15.95';
I='-4.514,5.503-6.133c-0.314-1.307,1.66,0.127,5.251,3.818c3.164,3.254,8.144,7.801,11.064,10.108c5.021,3.969,5.40';
J='-0.296l23.022-0.297l-5.762-8.254c-3.168-4.541-6.071-8.255-6.449-8.255s-2.347,2.371-4.377,5.271l-3.69';
K='-0.305v-15.445l21.001-0.299l21.001-0.299l-4.147-7.426c-6.226-11.145-5.641-10.877-10.19';
N='-0.756,4.306-1.53,4.306-1.727s-2.229-4.16-4.956-8.813l-4.958-8.462l-4.235,7.304c-2.32';
O=',4.437l3.226,4.436l7.71-6.021c4.24-3.313,10.413-7.842,13.716-10.063c4.644-3.121,5.89';
P='-4.654l-4.025,5.506h-23.713l0.156-16.187c0,0,9.811-0.366,21.283-0.366h20.85';
Q='c24.969,0,23.409,1.069,14.507-9.955l-4.778-5.918l-4.19,4.653l-4.18';
R=',315.664c1.356-0.563,2.697-1.021,2.978-1.021c0.038,0.376,0.06';
S='-3.035-2.771-3.035c-3.22,1.875-5.566,5.064-8.179,7.793l-23.60';
T=',5.615,3.396,6.215c0.18,0.891-15.211,8.006-15.609,7.213C';
U='-2.275-3.707-5.504-4.668-7.172c-0.961-1.67-2.20';
W=',314.583c0,0,8.866,27.05,12.34';
X=',4.654l-15.856-0.304l-15.85';
Y=',5.271l-27.793-0.132l-6.33';
d('<svg width="500" height="500">'+D);
d(r(r(r(r(r(r(r(r(r(r(r(r(r(r(r(r(r(r(r('DG408.997,122.382l3.629-2.032l-10.012-6.497l-10.009-6.497l-2.195,7.083c-2.958,9.552-8.487,20.773-14.003,28.416c-4.355,6.038-13.775,14.106-16.467,14.106c-1.68,0-1.755-0.338,1.861,8.345c1.729,4.151,3.555,8.729,4.06,10.174l0.918,2.628l3.079-2.823c1.695-1.553,2.253-3.035,8.304-4.512c6.57-2.126,17.534-4.232,19.088-3.667c0.664,0.242-2.23,5.356-6.649,11.744c-7.984,11.543-16.75,20.515-23.942,24.513l-4.021,2.23l2.822,5.478c1.553,3.012,3.536,6.505,4.409,7.765c1.581,2.29,1.583,2.29,5.064,0.121c4.438-2.765,10.479-4.206,26.281-6.271c6.966-0.912,14.321-1.902,16.349-2.202c3.173-0.472,3.769-0.204,4.293,1.928c0.602,3.25,0.421,6.658,1.686,9.72c1.433,2.916,2.298,2.712,6.408-1.512c6.831-7.014,5.967-13.847-3.337-26.405c-8.965-12.096-10.583-13.513-14.101-12.321l-2.938,0.995l4.938,9.333c2.719,5.134,4.939,9.727,4.939,10.207c-11.883,3.042-30.03,1.979-40.493-0.616c11.232-11.183,22.685-22.159,32.729-34.656c4.926-6.111,10.282-11.712,11.905-12.445c1.625-0.731,2.952-1.666,2.952-2.075c0-1.163-13.91-14.435-15.127-14.435c-0.598,0-1.084,0.441-1.084,0.98c0,0.54-1.685,5.007-3.74,9.931l-3.743,8.95h-15.509c-8.531,0-15.511-0.396-15.511-0.879C371.832,155.722,405.104,124.561,408.997,122.382zFG258.98,130.742c0.053,0.014,1.647-0.792,3.545-1.79c7.975-3.285-2.358-2.285,55.517-2.333l52.069-0.518l-10.669-10.107c-5.87-5.56-11.147-10.108-11.729-10.108s-5.587,2.333-11.124,5.184c-9.552,4.919-10.469,5.183-18.048,5.167l-7.983-0.018l3.958-2.316c2.174-1.272,4.808-3.489,5.847-4.924c5.623-7.761-5.982-19.346-28.117-28.067c-8.884-3.5-9.777-3.59-13.149-1.33l-2.516,1.685l8.925,8.95c4.908,4.921,10.896,11.744,13.305,15.16c2.41,3.415,5.583,7.258,7.053,8.539l2.671,2.327l-65.431,0.01L258.98,130.742zFG186.128R2,57.187,0.062,57.187l3.226O1I6H8-8.546c2.368N9,4.018-5.628,8.578-7.331,10.139c-3.63,3.326-3.103,3.846-9.879-9.668l-4.288-8.553h21.934Q9X5K2P6l-2.92-4.137c-1.606U8S1,0.083l-0.079-16.15l23.023J1Y3-4.694l-6.333-4.694v78.42h-6.791h-6.792l3.884,4.332C183.125,316.086,184.001,316.543,186.128,315.664z M204.417W7,32.667c1.747,2.82,3.275T204.395,356.627,204.417,314.583,204.417,314.583zFG261.965,181.771c1.221,9.539,1.402,12.767,1.438,25.451c0.021,7.555,0.445,13.736,0.945,13.736l17.965-4.775l46.482-0.927l0.329,2.951c0.243,2.176,0.775,2.827,2.026,2.48c17.15-4.759,18.48-5.351,17.973-8.02c-0.273-1.428-0.788-4.786-1.147-7.462l-0.65-4.867l5.256-3.307c4.265-2.687,4.999-3.544,3.904-4.574c-5.08-4.773-18.053-15.041-19.002-15.041c-0.636,0-3.405,1.167-6.154,2.591c-4.897,2.54-5.468,2.592-28.083,2.591c-21.454,0-30.73-0.863-40.001-3.72C261.818,178.44,261.602,178.93,261.965,181.771z M282.587,194.416l46.771-0.173l-0.059,10.129h-46.714L282.587,194.416L282.587,194.416zFG132.747,117.241c5.765,0,14.563-3.956,18.616-8.368c5.548-6.042,7.219-12.919,7.151-29.423l-0.058-14.067l290.407,0.713c-5.424,10.956-12.065,21.715-19.278,31.285c-0.598,0-2.317-0.685-3.823-1.522c-6.836-3.802-53.454-19.196-54.545-18.01c-0.255,0.278-0.558,1.815-0.671,3.417c-0.188,2.659,0.501,3.226,8.055,6.619c28.843,12.951,58.013,34.96,66.693,50.322c1.543,2.73,3.762,6.105,4.927,7.498c2.953,3.523,6.4,2.758,10.109-2.247c3.724-5.028,4.797-13.614,2.451-19.628c-2.584-6.627-9.453-13.933-16.926-18.004l-6.975-3.799l8.284-8.739c15.736-16.604,30.355-25.762,47.054-29.475l5.333-1.186L466.338,26.51l-19.287,25.631l-131.934-0.837c0-0.46,0.95-1.485,2.108-2.273c1.162-0.79,3.008-3.638,4.102-6.331c2.848-7.014,1.793-11.743-3.981-17.855c-5.167-5.468-21.688-14.674-36.105-20.121c-8.871-3.351-9.092-3.378-10.965-1.339c-1.873,2.04-1.717,2.346,7.752,15.212c9.431,12.81,16.824,26.532,16.824,31.215v2.329l-136.913-1.104c-0.07-0.606-0.209-1.476-0.309-1.931c-0.747-6.734-1.197-13.502-1.782-20.254l-8.098,0.669l-2.87,12.137c-4.672,19.751-12.426,37.031-21.287,47.445c-8.19,9.624-11.13,19.299-7.177,23.606C118.529,115.012,126.565,117.241,132.747,117.241zFG497.863,453.926c0,0-6.328,1.162-11.621,1.771c-53.488,6.135-95.518,8.235-164.648,8.235c-92.593,0-150.715-4.537-186.435-14.549c-21.072-5.908-37.036-18.377-43.876-34.272l-2.732-6.346l-0.556-207.73l8.155-6.395c4.486-3.517,8.03-6.792,7.876-7.278c-0.553-1.763-29.472-28.583-30.439-28.232c-0.547,0.199-4.038,5.058-7.757,10.798l-6.765,10.436l-28.088,0.552l-28.089,0.551l9.016,9.771l9.016,9.771l8.486-2.245c12.449-3.293,19.834-4.607,25.896-4.607h5.386v208.28L0,454.15l27.968,27.782c0.589-0.797,6.647-11.381,13.463-23.516c6.816-12.139,14.04-24.721,16.056-27.961c4.235-6.812,10.905-13.735,12.644-13.133c0.658,0.229,6.095,8.291,12.084,17.92c12.337,19.834,13.402,21.227,20.836,27.254c22.951,18.607,65.076,28.838,128.873,31.293c74.453,2.68,148.922,4.115,223.418,3.92l1.873-5.76c3.664-11.26,17.123-22.103,33.396-26.896l6.779-2v-4.248C497.389,456.469,497.863,453.926,497.863,453.926zFG67.377,99.175c3.615,13.117,7.038,20.628,10.361,22.734c4.389,2.782,9.84,0.074,15.801-7.847c6.25-8.306,9.067-16.414,9.077-26.118c0.018-20.292-12.427-36.144-44.859-57.137c-7.896-5.112-24.133-14.715-24.878-14.715c-1.627,1.909-3.001,4.063-4.373,6.208l5.627,7.655C50.934,52.805,59.531,70.706,67.377,99.175zFG173.771,362.742l0.52-190.884l3.063-2.758l3.062-2.759l-7.109-7.678l-7.108-7.678l-3.356,3.542c-3.192,3.369-3.737,3.542-11.244,3.542c-6.402,0-9.319-0.623-15.48-3.311c-4.175-1.82-8.006-3.31-8.513-3.31c-0.549,0-0.621,11.039-0.176,27.31c0.955,34.97,0.958,91.285,0.006,111.164c-1.267,26.447-4.287,49.291-9.586,72.48c-3.079,13.479-3.482,16.498-2.39,17.932c0.721,0.947,1.631,1.721,2.021,1.721c1.117,0,8.793-15.195,12.104-23.961c5.931-15.701,10.866-37.443,12.781-56.309l0.701-6.898h17.026l-1.326,55.17c-1.423,3.031-2.515,3.168-13.619,1.717c-6.279-0.819-6.333-0.807-6.333,1.927c0,1.928,2.073,5.016,6.923,10.313c4.599,5.021,7.539,9.328,8.759,12.826c1.563,4.484,2.151,5.162,3.969,4.582c5.182-1.656,9.604-6.027,12.419-12.273L173.771,362.742z M160.092,286.059h-17.225v-55.169h17.225V286.059z M160.092,222.062h-17.225V169.1h17.225V222.062zFG293.07,161.867l-28.633,0.519l9.645,13.688l4.053-1.601c9.032-3.139-3.802-2.639,40.807-2.178l36.75-0.577l-9.136-9.302l-9.138-9.302l-15.717,8.237L293.07,161.867zFG222.14,68.533l-13.546,14.79c-10.902,11.906-16.242,16.731-27.367,24.737c-13.609,9.792-34.075,21.463-47.984,27.362c-8.677,3.68-8.933,3.929-7.692,7.482l0.995,2.851l11.961-3.866c26.478-8.556,46.305-17.892,73.013-34.374c22.589-13.94,23.673-14.466,32.708-15.858l8.12-1.25l-15.104-10.938L222.14,68.533zFG346.897,139.838c-4.937-4.418-9.556-8.035-10.266-8.035c-0.711,0-4.132,1.274-7.604,2.83c-6.304,2.824-6.376,2.832-36.464,3.368l-30.149,0.54l9.534,13.669L280.5,149c20.153-0.787,75.367-1.13,75.367-1.13L346.897,139.838zFG191.97,200.99l-7.131,5.135l3.792,7.141c2.085,3.927,4.154,7.11,4.598,7.071s2.631-0.968,4.859-2.064c4.674-2.301,15.125-4.473,32.423-6.736c6.687-0.875,12.5-1.596,12.919-1.602c0.418-0.005,0.76,1.944,0.76,4.333s0.445,5.615,0.988,7.172c1.354,3.878,2.733,3.569,7.275-1.629c3.089-3.538,3.895-5.307,3.886-8.552c-0.012-5.345-4.213-13.069-12.353-22.718c-6.06-7.182-6.586-7.55-9.729-6.798l-3.324,0.795l2.109,3.488c2.306,3.813,8.108,15.761,8.108,16.697c0,0.321-9.46,0.571-21.024,0.557l-21.024-0.027l5.573-5.173c9.319-8.649,25.171-25.794,30.967-33.491c3.499-4.647,7.001-8.021,9.703-9.348l4.227-2.077l-7.502-7.476c-4.127-4.112-7.962-7.478-8.522-7.478c-0.56-0.001-2.04,2.853-3.289,6.343c-1.25,3.49-3.177,7.958-4.286,9.931l-2.016,3.586h-15.214c-8.367,0-15.214-0.389-15.214-0.863c0-1.57,32.485-31.646,36.547-33.836c2.19-1.181,3.977-2.423,3.971-2.758c-0.01-0.471-16.511-11.646-19.253-13.038c-0.314-0.159-1.139,2.018-1.831,4.838c-4.399,17.911-17.597,37.768-28.624,43.065c-2.208,1.061-3.893,2.242-3.744,2.625c0.147,0.384,2.041,4.976,4.206,10.205l3.936,9.507l3.157-2.587c1.735-1.424,1.981-2.978,7.862-4.304c5.551-2.023,17.526-4.417,19.151-3.827c1.393,0.506-8.597,15.994-15.084,23.384C201.226,193.434,195.893,198.165,191.97,200.99zFDG212.273,453.381c3.344,0.342,48.484,0.586,100.309,0.541c104.205-0.092,103.413-0.051,118.041-5.967c5.849-2.363,13.173-7.344,13.173-8.955c0-0.326-1.924-1.367-4.281-2.314c-6.762-2.721-13.946-8.301-16.041-12.454c-1.045-2.07-2.46-6.722-3.145-10.333l-1.247-6.569h-7.71l-0.052,8.836c-0.064,11.17-0.775,16.463-2.543,18.949c-0.769,1.08-3.727,3.758-7.037,3.852c-75.582,2.135-45.149,2.668-178.322,1.857l-3.958-2.023c-7.031-3.596-8.162-5.832-8.495-16.811l-0.294-9.677l7.403-9.295c-0.404-0.127-7.347-2.629-15.428-5.555l-14.692-5.318l-0.294,17.783c-0.404,24.496,0.977,30.943,7.974,37.199C199.686,450.748,204.608,452.6,212.273,453.381zFG154.256,404.033c-8.408,11.227-12.161,14.928-23.174,22.85c-9.769,7.023-12.531,9.717-12.531,12.219c0,2.013,2.844,4.125,7.092,5.271c5.889,1.586,15.512,0.643,20.592-2.021c11.565-6.061,17.982-18.053,19.518-36.479l0.688-8.248l-2.993-0.937C160.487,395.766,160.388,395.846,154.256,404.033zFG467.429,427.342c7.128,6.679,13.961,12.64,15.182,13.246c2.935,1.459,3.889,1.433,6.477-0.188c4.783-2.996,7.222-17.277,3.925-22.98c-2.907-5.024-19.268-12.119-49.51-21.471l-6.883-2.13l-1.896,2.789l-1.896,2.789l10.818,7.902C449.596,411.645,460.298,420.664,467.429,427.342zFG269.754,387.078c23.155,8.477,43.153,21.201,61.019,38.826c4.429,4.369,9.442,8.715,11.146,9.653c5.188,2.869,9.702,1.068,12.854-5.127c3.214-6.315,1.988-12.452-3.85-19.299c-7.554-8.856-35.523-19.508-81.013-30.853c-5.78-1.442-6.18-1.364-7.217,1.421C261.796,384.111,261.941,384.221,269.754,387.078zFEDG467.412,353.047c-2.155,3.582-4.95,3.83-15.26,1.361c-8.745-2.096-8.292-2.172-8.292,1.41c0.002,2.524,0.918,3.666,4.922,6.123c7.375,4.526,13.388,10.608,15.398,15.578l1.795,4.434l3.04-1.924c4.878-3.088,12.663-13.078,14.016-17.979c0.923-3.36,1.241-28.937,1.241-99.608c0-94.833,0.008-95.104,2.189-98.953c1.205-2.123,2.022-4.032,1.813-4.239c-1.136-1.142-19.828-13.102-20.033-12.818c0.024,38.464,2.318,76.997,1.136,115.494C469.258,344.197,469.128,350.195,467.412,353.047zFG460.258,187.415c-0.833-0.828-19.634-12.998-20.08-12.998c-0.276,0-0.206,1.396,0.158,3.104c0.88,4.141,0.673,134.569,0.673,134.569l-1.222,13.625l4.368-2.914c2.401-1.604,6.139-4.033,8.304-5.404c3.392-2.143,3.833-2.873,3.206-5.307c-2.539-38.09-0.279-76.467-1.546-114.606l3.234-4.867C459.136,189.939,460.443,187.599,460.258,187.415zFEDG324.872,336.477c0.914,3.049,2.071,6.414,2.574,7.476c0.503,1.063,1.563,1.934,2.354,1.934c1.909,0,6.542-8.731,7.288-13.739c0.53-3.578,0.188-4.396-3.511-8.222c-7.599-7.87-18.464-13.133-18.464-8.938c0,0.475,1.821,4.258,4.047,8.406C321.389,327.535,323.957,333.424,324.872,336.477zFG305.599,322.059c-4.9-3.918-6.319-4.567-7.93-3.629c-1.078,0.629-1.729,1.725-1.446,2.437c5.487,13.84,7.747,19.838,7.747,20.557c0,0.486,0.688,2.681,1.534,4.879c0.843,2.197,2.206,3.996,3.025,3.996c2.134,0,6.729-8.422,7.35-13.467C316.503,331.787,314.914,329.504,305.599,322.059zFG267.803,322.389l-2.938,0.803c-1.614,0.443-2.983,0.89-3.041,0.99c-0.06,0.103-1.337,3.164-2.841,6.805c-1.502,3.642-5.028,10.438-7.834,15.105c-2.808,4.664-4.946,9.367-4.754,10.451c0.192,1.086,1.484,2.6,2.874,3.363c3.453,1.902,5.027,1.771,8.807-0.736c5.485-3.646,8.052-11.264,9.083-26.965L267.803,322.389zFG292.098,349.443c5.434-10.875,4.582-14.133-6.117-23.508c-6.394-5.601-7.758-6.367-9.508-5.349c-1.121,0.654-1.82,1.772-1.552,2.483c0.871,2.291,7.397,20.984,9.218,26.396C286.454,356.352,288.646,356.346,292.098,349.443zFG358.401,313.439c0.123-1.76,1.138-4.265,2.258-5.562l2.036-2.36l-7.324-6.765l-7.323-6.762l-6.177,6.446h-29.793v-8.83h37.606l-5.834-7.723c-3.209-4.248-6.22-7.723-6.688-7.723c-0.467,0-2.638,0.994-4.822,2.205c-6.396,3.053-13.453,2.074-20.265,2.207v-9.93h37.669l-8.936-11.33l-3.434-4.158l-4.488,2.227c-3.313,1.645-6.624,2.227-12.65,2.227h-8.161v-9.929h23.938h23.941l-10.257-8.925l-10.26-8.924l-5.087,3.407l-5.085,3.409h-28.884h-28.885l-6.724-3.319c-3.697-1.827-6.853-3.181-7.01-3.009c-0.158,0.172,0.092,4.273,0.555,9.113c1.08,11.3,1.058,51.577-0.039,67.229c-0.467,6.647-0.75,12.157-0.631,12.248c0.119,0.088,4.18-0.32,9.025-0.906l8.811-1.063l0.31-3.459l0.31-3.457h32.93h32.93l-0.027,11.033c-0.035,14.659-2.152,22.293-7.934,28.588c-5.641,6.143-10.338,7.366-28.119,7.342c-7.742-0.01-14.074,0.404-14.074,0.924c0,1.494,2.207,2.934,6.586,4.293c7.826,2.428,15.965,9.639,17.98,15.93c0.399,1.252,9.794-1.801,15.963-5.188c8.899-4.885,15.709-11.869,19.164-19.662c2.923-6.592,6.166-20.684,6.166-26.797C357.673,324.498,358.316,314.664,358.401,313.439z M275.777,251.361l0.33-3.128h21.277v8.828l-10.402,0.314C275.643,257.719,275.139,257.449,275.777,251.361z M297.893,298.439h-22.291v-8.83h22.291V298.439z M297.386,278.023l-21.075-0.148c-0.968-2.947-0.68-6.131-0.709-9.23h22.408L297.386,278.023zFEG365.116R3,57.187,0.063,57.187l3.227O2I5H9-8.546c2.367N8,4.018-5.628,8.578-7.33,10.139c-3.631,3.326-3.104,3.846-9.88-9.668l-4.288-8.553h21.935Q8X4K1P5l-2.92-4.137c-1.605U7S2,0.083l-0.079-16.15l23.022JY4-4.694l-6.332-4.694v78.42h-6.791h-6.793l3.885,4.332C362.113,316.086,362.989,316.543,365.116,315.664z M383.404W8,32.667c1.746,2.82,3.274T383.383,356.627,383.404,314.583,383.404,314.583zFE',/D/g,D),/E/g,E),/F/g,F),/G/g,G),/H/g,H),/I/g,I),/J/g,J),/K/g,K),/N/g,N),/O/g,O),/P/g,P),/Q/g,Q),/R/g,R),/S/g,S),/T/g,T),/U/g,U),/W/g,W),/X/g,X),/Y/g,Y) +'</svg>');</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for using my obfuscatweet tool :D, but the score must be counted in bytes and not chars :(

Answer (score 2):

### Java - 9711 <s>9826</s> bytes

```
import java.io.*;import java.util.zip.*;class b{public static void main(String[]v)throws Exception{ByteArrayInputStream c=new ByteArrayInputStream(java.util.Base64.getDecoder().decode("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".getBytes()));ZipInputStream z=new ZipInputStream(c);byte[]a=new byte[15498];z.getNextEntry();for(int j=0;j<15498;j++){a[j]=(byte)z.read();}a[15497]=0;System.out.print(new String(a));}}
```

```
I felt free to  remove the comment in the original svg, removed some
whitespaces and saved it 115 bytes because of being better to compress.
```

Tried to make it as short as possible.
Seems like I need a better compression algorithm but I think it's good enough for my second post on StackExchange.

Ungolfed source (for understanding the code):

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.zip.*;

class b {
public static void main(String[] v) throws Exception {
    ByteArrayInputStream c = new ByteArrayInputStream(
            java.util.Base64
                    .getDecoder()
                .decode("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"
                            .getBytes()));
    ZipInputStream z = new ZipInputStream(c);
    byte[] a = new byte[15498];
    z.getNextEntry();
    for (int j = 0; j < 15498; j++) {
        a[j] = (byte) z.read();
    }
    a[15497] = 0;
    System.out.print(new String(a));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Python 2.7, 9279 bytes

```
import zlib,base64
print zlib.decompress(base64.b64decode('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'))
```